# Prove that the number of zero divisors in $\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$ for specific element $k$ is $n / \mbox{ggT}(n,k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $k$ and $n$ be two given natural numbers, then
\begin{align*}
\left| \left\{ i \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\} : n \mbox{ divides } i \cdot k \} \right\} \right| 
 & = \frac{n}{\operatorname{ggT}(n,k)}
\end{align*}
where because this set could be written as $|\{ i \in \{0,\ldots, n-1\} : i\cdot k \equiv 0 \pmod{n} \}|$
this is the number of zero divisors in $\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$ for $[k]$.

By plugging in some numbers, for example $n = 15, k = 6$ this seems to be true. But how to prove it?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=\gcd(n,k)$ and write $n=dn'$ and $k=dk'$.

Then $n$ divides $ik$ iff $n'$ divides $ik'$.

Since $\gcd(n',k')=1$, we have $n'$ divides $ik'$ iff $n'$ divides $i$.

Therefore, there are $\dfrac{n}{n'}=d$ possibilities for $i$.